# How to do app bar in Marshmallow-only app

Tags: android, android-actionbar, toolbar

I'm a newbie, trying to do a specialized app for a tablet that will function as a USB MIDI device, so it will require Marshmallow. I may also allow it to run in a crippled mode on KitKat or Lollipop, but never on older devices. Yet I'm hopelessly confused by the tons of stuff I've been reading about ActionBar vs. Toolbar. Much of what I've read has been contradictory.

If I want to have complete control over the app bar, including perhaps even making it disappear, and only need to run on recent Android, what should I use, and why? Many things seem to steer me to the V7 appcompat library, but that seems to be for backward compatibility that I don't need. Or is it?

Answer (score 0):

Use this Co-ordinate layout

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent">

 <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

     <!-- Your scrolling content -->

 </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

 <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_width="match_parent">

     <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
             ...
             app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>

     <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
             ...
             app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>

 </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Source [Click  Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/AppBarLayout.html)

Comment: That looks way more complicated than I need. I just need to put some text and icon buttons of my choice in the app bar, and sometimes make it go away. But my main question is whether, if I only want to run on API 21 and up, I need a support library at all, since it is advertised as a way to get compatibility with old Android versions. Can I do what I want without a support library or appcompat library, just using native controls? If so, would that be an ActionBar or a Toolbar, or what?

Comment: with out support library  then i don't know